# Using preg_replace not working properly

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace everything in a string that is not a word,space,comma,period,question mark,exclamation mark,asterisk or `&#039;`. I'm trying to do it using preg_replace, but not getting the correct results:

```
$string = "i don&#039;t know if i can do this,.?!*!@#$%^&()_+123|";
preg_replace("~(?![\w\s]+|[\,\.\?\!\*]+|&#039;|)~", "", $string);

echo $string;
```

**Result:**

i don't know if i can do this,.?!!*@#$%^&()_+123|

**Need Result:**

i don't know if i can do this,.?!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're happy to call `html_entity_decode` first to convert that `&#039;` into an apostrophe. If you are, then probably the simplest way to achieve this is

```
// Convert HTML entities to characters
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);
// Remove characters other than the specified list.
$string = preg_replace("~[^\w\s,.?!*']+~", "", $string);
// Convert characters back to HTML entities. This will convert the ' back to &#039;
$string = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

If not, then you'll need to use some negative [assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to remove `&` when not followed by `#`, `;` when not preceded by `&#039`, and so on.

```
$string = preg_replace("~[^\w\s,.?!*'&#;]+|&(?!#)|&#(?!039;)|(?<!&)#|(?<!&#039);~", "", $string);
```

The results are subtly different. The first block of code, when provided `&quot;`, will convert it to `"` and then remove it from the string. The second block will remove `&` and `;` and leave `quot` behind in the result.

Comment: First option is better, and neater.